# How to add an item to iOS Listview

Tags: c#, ios, listview, xamarin

I am creating just a simple application using Xamarin.iOS. I have searched everywhere for how to input an item into a listview using Xamarin c#. Here is my code

```
public void setallcards()
    {

        foreach(flashcards cards in Quizmode.Application.allcards)
        {
            //Input all flashcardfile names here
            //cards.getname() returns a string
            Allflashcard_editcards.Add (cards.getname());
        }
    }
```

I understand it would be simple. I have no idea though, as I have just started trying to use Xamarin.iOS to create iPhone apps.

Comment: Ya that is what I meant. I have looked there but how do I transfer from a string to the required format? @Jason

Comment: The data source for your table with have a GetCell() method.  That is where you build and fill in the content of an individual cell.  You would assign your string data to a cell in that method.  See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/.  Note that in my earlier comment I linked to the wrong doc

Comment: Thanks. Let me check that and I will let you know soon.